# How to make my csv/excel file compile data from multiple outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-re

Making a code that scans my emails looking for a certain pattern. My goal is to make a csv file with all the occurrences listed in one file, but my code adds ONLY the last email into the csv. Here's the input:

```
pattern = re.compile(
            r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
matches = pattern.finditer(body)

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerows(map(lambda m: m.groups(), matches))
```

The emails ran through are the following:

First email:

```
PUU128378 Line 20 Seq 1 5/22/2023

PUN102939 Line 100 Seq 8 11/1/2024

PUU012939 Line 120 Seq 4 1/1/2025
```

Second email:

```
PUU128377 Line 20 Seq 1 5/22/2023

PUN102938 Line 100 Seq 8 11/1/2024

PUU012938 Line 120 Seq 4 1/1/2025
```

The excel file looks like:

[image]

I would like it to look like:

[image]

rest of my code:

```
for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
    # fetch the email message by ID
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)
            # decode email sender
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance(From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("From:", From)
            
            # if the email message is multipart
            if msg.is_multipart():
                # iterate over email parts
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                    try:
                        # get the email body
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    except:
                        pass
                    
                    if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                        # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                            pattern = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
                            matches = pattern.finditer(body)
                            with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
                                writer = csv.writer(f_out)
                                writer.writerows(map(lambda m: m.groups(), matches))
                            for match in matches:
                                print(match)
```

New Edit

```
with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
    # fetch the email message by ID
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)
            # decode email sender
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance(From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("From:", From)

                # iterate over email parts
            for part in msg.walk():
                # extract content type of email
                content_type = part.get_content_type()
                content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                if payload is None:
                    continue
                body = payload.decode()
                    
                pattern = re.compile(
                    r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
                matches = pattern.finditer(body)
                writer.writerows(map(lambda m: m.groups(), matches))
```

Comment: i'm a bit confused? these are not emails, though i might be missing something.

Comment: @rv.kvetch sorry haha. the text under "first email:" and "second email:" is what was sent in the email that my code scanned into body

Comment: The `with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:` will overwrite any existing file each time it's executed — so it you apply it to each email body separately, you'll end up with only that last one. The fix is relatively simple but you haven't shown the source of `body` variable.

Comment: @martineau the source of body variable is my email (body is meant to extract each email while my code finds the pattern in each and hopefully exports the pattern to a csv). The two emails that are "body" are the "First Email" and "Second Email" listed above.

Comment: I understand what `body` is. However to show you how to do what you want properly, the steps involved include it's (repeated) creation for each email message — which is why I asked. Please add the code for that to your question.

Comment: @martineau got it. my mistake. I just added most of the rest of the code. let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only getting the last email put into the CSV file is because your code *overwrites* any existing `.csv` file each time it processes a message. The solution is to only open the file for writing *once* outside the message retrieval loop.

Below is an outline of what I'm suggesting based on the code you added to your question:

```
with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    pattern = re.compile(
        r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")

    for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
        # fetch the email message by ID
        res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
        for response in msg:
            ...
            try:
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
            except:  # NOTE it is bad to have non-specific except clauses like this.
                pass
            ...
            if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                matches = pattern.finditer(body)
                writer.writerows(map(lambda m: m.groups(), matches))
                for match in matches:
                    print(match)
```

Comment: That didn't work for me.. returned it blank. The output is just the 'BYE' message so it's not printing the matches and *i think* not defining body. any other suggestions? Also, the line below try: and the line of if content_type == both say part is undefined

Comment: did I copy and paste it in the wrong area? where should I put it?

Comment: Obviously I can't tell if you copied and pasted the code properly, nor could I test the code in my answer myself. Regardless, you should be able to implement the main idea — only opening "data.csv" once — into your own code. Note that you may be not seeing errors that are happening because of that "naked" `except:` you have in your code (which ignores them).

Comment: Alright. I just used your advice, and I put my New Edit in my original post. However, now it gives me a ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. Did I close it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it got closed automatically at the end of the `with open...`. You need to indent the entire `for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):` loop as shown in my answer (so the file is not closed until all the messages have been processed.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, it's writing them into the csv how I want. Only thing, it writes each occurence twice. Any idea why? I updated the New Edit with the working code